# ansible stat then copy with_items

Tags: ansible

I have this repetitive pattern::

```
- stat: path={{ home }}/.vimrc
  register: st
- copy: src=.vimrc dest={{ home }}/.vimrc
  when: not st.stat.exists

- stat: path={{ home }}/.gitconfig
  register: st
- copy: src=.vimrc dest={{ home }}/.gitconfig
  when: not st.stat.exists
...
```

How can I do it using **with_items** for a big list ?::

```
 with_items:
    - .vimrc
    - .bashrc
    - .profile
    - .gitconfig
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometime you even don't want to copy the file, if the file exists on the destination computer even the content differ. Then you can use like this(didn't test it in your scenario but I think it will work)

```
- stat: path="{{ home }}/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - .vimrc
    - .bashrc
    - .profile
    - .gitconfig
  register: st


- copy: src="{{ item.item }}" dest="{{ home }}/{{ item.item }}"
  with_items: "{{ st.results }}"
  when: not item.stat.exists
```

Hope that help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the force parameter:

```
- copy: src={{ item }} dest={{ home }}/{{ item }} force=no
  with_items:
    - .vimrc
    - .bashrc
    - .profile
    - .gitconfig
```

Force=no writes a file only if it doesn't exist yet.
I think that is exactly what you want.

Comment: Side note: I use Arbab Nazar solution because of cp limitaion when using option: directory_mode and remote_src. see documentation [Ansible copy options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html#options)